# Dynamics AX 2012 R3 on Azure, unable to RDP

Tags: azure, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I used this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/microsoft/microsoft_dynamics_lcs/ and provisioned an instance of Dynamics AX 2012 R3 on Azure, it took a long time to Deploy and finally it did, but how do i access the instance. I downloaded the RDP file which is available on the Azure Portal, i cannot RDP into the instance. Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take a look at the help section, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The information to access your vm is available in the Lifecycle Services project that you used to the deploy the instance.

Comment: Are you still unable to RDP? Sometimes it just takes a while to start working. The RDP is not on port 3389, and in the RDP file you can see the port it is trying to connect to in notepad easily. See if the port is open in Azure.

Comment: Hi Alex, I was not able to, However, i killed the entire instance and started from scratch and it worked. Weird!!!